# D trie implementation

Tags: strings, trie, d

I just started to learn D and ported my a bit over-templated trie. It looks way better than on C++.

I'm sure there is still room for improvement and to make it be real D code.

I checked an the array appending is doing x2 pre-allocation on resize (although 1.5 seems to friendlier, but for my use both are ok). Does this have other performance problems?

```
import std.stdio;     // I/O
import std.typecons;  // Nullable
import std.algorithm; // map
import std.array;     // splitter
```

//**Tokenizer**

```
interface Tokenizer(Word, Token) {
    Token encode(Word  w);
    Word  decode(Token t);

    final:
    Token[] encode(ref Word[]  ws){
        return ws.map!(w => encode(w)).array;
    }
    Word[]  decode(ref Token[] ts){
        return ts.map!(t => decode(t)).array;
    }
}

class VectorTokenizer(Word) : Tokenizer!(Word, size_t) {
    Word[]       alphabet;
    size_t[Word] index;

    size_t encode(Word  w) {
        if(auto i = w in index)
            return *i;

        auto t = alphabet.length;
        alphabet ~= w;
        return index[w] = t;
    }
    Word  decode(size_t i) {
        return alphabet[i];
    }
}
```

//**Trie**

//Node

```
class TrieNode(Data, Word) {
    Nullable!Data data;
    TrieNode[Word] children;

    Word word;
    size_t depth;
    TrieNode parent;

    this() {}
    this(TrieNode p, Word w) {
        if(p) {
            parent = p;
            depth = parent.depth+1;
        }
        word = w;
    }

    nothrow
    bool put(Word[] path, Data d, size_t i=0) {
        if(path.length==i) {
            // Update leaf
            bool r = data.isNull;
            data = d;
            return r;
        }

        // Look for leaf
        auto w = path[i];
        if(auto cn = w in children)  // Inside subtree
            return cn.put(path, d, i+1);
        else {  // On new subtree
            children[w] = new TrieNode(this, w);
            return children[w].put(path, d, i+1);
        }
    }

    nothrow
    Nullable!Data get(Word[] path, size_t i=0) {
        if(path.length==i)
            return data;

        // Look for leaf
        if(auto cn = path[i] in children)
            return cn.get(path, i+1);

        // Not here =/
        return Nullable!Data.init;
    }

    void print(string indent="", bool lastChild=true) {
        // Print tree indent
        string branch = lastChild ? "┕━" : "┝━";
        writef("%s%s '%s'", indent, branch, word);

        // Print data
        if(!data.isNull)
            writef("->'%s'", data);
        writef(":\n");

        // Print children
        string newIndent = indent ~ (lastChild ? "  " : "│ ");
        auto i=0;
        auto lastIndex = children.length;
        foreach(c; children)
            c.print(newIndent, ++i==lastIndex);
    }

}
```

//Trie

```
class Trie(Data, Word) {
    auto _root = new TrieNode!(Data, Word);
    size_t _length;

    nothrow
    auto put(Word[] path, Data d) {
        auto r = _root.put(path, d, 0);
        if (r)
            _length++;
        return r;
    }
    nothrow
    auto get(Word[] path) {
        return _root.get(path);
    }

    void print() {
        writef("Trie |%s|:\n", _length);
        auto i=0;
        auto lastIndex = _root.children.length;
        foreach(n; _root.children)
            n.print("", ++i==lastIndex);
    }

    @property nothrow
    auto length() {
        return _length;
    }
}
```

//**Trie Specializations**

//Tokenized Trie

```
class TokenizedTrie(
        Data,
        Word, Token,
        Compressor: Tokenizer!(Word, Token)
        ) : Trie!(Data, Token) {
    Compressor c;

    this() {
        c = new Compressor();
    }
    this(Compressor compressor) {
        c = compressor;
    }

    bool put(Word[] path, Data d) {
        Token[] tokenPath = path.map!(w => c.encode(w)).array;
        return Trie!(Data, Token).put(tokenPath, d);
    }

    Nullable!Data get(Word[] path) {
        Token[] tokenPath = path.map!(w => c.encode(w)).array;
        return Trie!(Data, Token).get(tokenPath);
    }
}
```

//Iri Trie

```
class IriTrie(
   Data
   ) : TokenizedTrie!(Data,  string, size_t, VectorTokenizer!(string)) {
 bool put(string iri, Data d) {
   string[] path = iri.split('/');
   return TokenizedTrie!(Data, string, size_t, VectorTokenizer!(string)).put(path, d);
 }
 Nullable!Data get(string iri) {
   string[] path = iri.split('/');
   return TokenizedTrie!(Data, string, size_t, VectorTokenizer!(string)).get(path);
 }
}
```

//**main**

//Sample usage:

```
void main() {
    auto trie = new Trie!(string, string);
    trie.put(["http:", "", "doge.ing.puc.cl"], "aoeu");
    trie.put(["http:", "", "forum.dlang.org"], "htns");
    trie.print();

    auto tTrie = new TokenizedTrie!(string, string, size_t, VectorTokenizer!(string));
    tTrie.put(["http:", "", "doge.ing.puc.cl"], "aoeu");
    tTrie.put(["http:", "", "forum.dlang.org"], "htns");
    tTrie.print();

    auto iriTrie = new IriTrie!(string);
    iriTrie.put("http://doge.ing.puc.cl", "aoeu");
    iriTrie.put("http://forum.dlang.org", "htns");
    iriTrie.print();
}
```